UTF-8 encoding error for Loggin with Google
public static String getToken(String code) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException { 
        String response = Request.Post(Constants.GOOGLE_LINK_GET_TOKEN) 
                .bodyForm(  Form.form().add("client_id", Constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID).add("client_secret", Constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET) 
                           .add("redirect_uri", Constants.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI)
                           .add("code", code)
                           .add("grant_type", Constants.GOOGLE_GRANT_TYPE) 
                           .build() 
                        ) 
                .execute().returnContent().asString(Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
        JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(response, JsonObject.class);

        String accessToken = jobj.get("access_token").toString().replaceAll("\"", "");

        return accessToken; 
    }

public static Account getUserInfo(final String accessToken) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String link = Constants.GOOGLE_LINK_GET_USER_INFO + accessToken;

    // Take Response Google API
    String response = Request.Get(link).execute().returnContent().asString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
 
    JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(response, JsonObject.class);
   
    String fullName = jobj.get("name").getAsString();
    System.out.println("Full Name: " + fullName);  

    Account googlePojo = new Gson().fromJson(response, Account.class); 
    googlePojo.setFullName(fullName);

    return googlePojo;
}

The out put is
Full Name: Ng?c Khánh Hu?nh
I dont know utf-8 is not work. I not sure this charset.foName("Utf-8") is correct or i wrong something in the getUserInfor function

What do you expect it to be? Is the place where you're printing that set up for Unicode and does it have the glyphs? What does System.out.println(java.util.HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ").formatHex(fullName.getBytes())); print?

I mean when i take the object is my Account from google and I want this fileName is Ngọc khánh Huỳnh instead of Ng?c Khánh Hu?nh so I think i use charset utf-8 .

You didn't post the output

I got it , it just error font when I Print on output but it not error font when i save in database.

Well, you have an error.
